# A better 1d interpolation method than Cubic/Quadratic Splines

Tags: interpolation, spline, cubic-spline

I was searching for the best interpolation methods that give class C2 functions and found that cubic spline interpolation was the most used. However, when I tested it, although it performed better than Lagrange interpolation, the function still diverged too far from the given points at certain intervals like shown in this example: [Interpolation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI2IW.png)

So I was wondering if there is a better interpolation method that will help reduce these gaps.

Comment: Why do you think that the function diverges "too far" ??

Comment: The cubic and quadratic splines appear to pass exactly through the points you provided.

Comment: Yes I know that the function passes through the points provided, but if we take for example f(110) it gives a value of approximately -40 which is very different from the values at 100 and 120.

Comment: Okay, so you want the interpolated values to be close to the linear interpolation. You could use cubic Beziers. [This Wikipedia section talks about how to get C2 continuity across the join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_B%C3%A9zier_curve#Smooth_joining).